# sum of natural number between range

Tags: python

This is a question I've been asked in a job interview.

The question is how to sum all natural numbers between 1 to 100, and I asked to write this program in python as well.

That was the code I wrote:

```
def sumNaturalNumbers(start, end, total_sum):
    li = range(start, end)
    sum = li[0] + li[-1]
    li.remove(li[0])
    li.remove(li[-1])
    total_sum += sum
    if len(li) == 0:
        return total_sum
    return sumNaturalNumbers(li[0], li[-1]+1, total_sum)

print sumNaturalNumbers(1,101, 0)
```

Is there anything I could change\fix to make this function more pythonic, so I can improve myself at the next job interview?

**EDIT**

My intention was to sum the first and last item in the list each iteration which is 101 and to multiply it by 50. I was asking to show my way of thinking and then after explain it, to implement it.
**I know the function sum, but I needed to implement this in that way.**

Comment: You'd probably impress them more if you used the formula `n*(n+1)/2` to sum `1...n` (it's constant in complexity, summing a range is linear).

Comment: @ajcr i know the formula in that format ((1+n)*100)/2, but i was asked for my way of thinking and not formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
def sum_gauss(start, end):
    return ((end-start+1)/2) * (end+start)
```

(In Python 2 you'll need `from __future__ import division`)

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in function `sum`, that sums the inputted list:

```
sum(range(start, stop+1))
```

---

```
>>> sum(range(1, 11)) #Sum of numbers between 1 and 10, inclusive
55
>>> sum(range(1, 101)) #Sum of numbers between 1 and 100, inclusive
5050
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_nums_in_range(start, end):
    repeating_sum = 0
    li = range(start, end + 1)
    first_half = li[:len(li)/2]
    second_half = li[len(li)/2:]
    for a, b in zip(first_half, reversed(second_half)):
         repeating_sum = a+b

    return repeating_sum * len(li)/2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are supposed to recurse, a simple way would be just remove 1 from end until you reach start:

```
def sumNaturalNumbers(start, end):
    if end == start:
        return start
    return end + sumNaturalNumbers(start, end-1)
```

Comment: recurse is not a must, the intention was gauss.

Comment: @omri_saadon, what are the actual conditions, if not recursion why were you not allowed to sum?

Comment: he gave me a piece of paper and asked for the answer of the sum of the natural numbers, after i wrote the sum he asked how did i get to that answer. after explaining to him my way, he asked me to implement it in python in the same way.

Comment: so you want a solution using your own logic?

Answer (score 1):

```
def sumNaturalNumbers(start, end):
    return (start + end) * (end - start + 1) // 2

>>> sumNaturalNumbers(1, 10)
55
>>> sumNaturalNumbers(1, 100)
5050
```

Answer (score 1):

Comments in-line

```
def foo(start, end):
    '''return the sum of the range start --> end
    '''
    # sum([2,3,4]) == sum([2,2,2]) + sum([0,1,2]) 
    # first part of the sum is the min value times the length
    n = end - start
    b = start * n
    # the second part is the sum of the difference between the
    # min value and all the other items
    # this turns out to be equivalent to sum(range(1, n-1))
    # applying the infamous formula to this range
    m = n-1
    c = m*(m+1)/2
    # return the sum of the two parts
    return b + c

>>> 
>>> foo(1,10)
45
>>> foo(2,11)
54
>>> foo(2,10)
44
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sumBetween(lower, upper):
    return sum(range(lower, upper))
sumBetween(1,101)
```

Why complicate things when they are simple ?

Answer (score -1):

```
x = (lambda x: ((x * x + x)/2))(100)
print(x)
# aka 
print((lambda x: ((x * x + x)/2))(100))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).